# Print all lines of a text file containing the same duplicated word

Tags: performance, beginner, file, go

I'm implementing my very first Go application and I would like to receive an hint on how to make a certain check faster.

I have a huge `txt` file in which each line is structured like the following:

```
key text
key text
   .
   .
key text
```

Where `key` is ALWAYS 6 HEX digits long and `text` is ALWAYS 16 HEX digits long.

> I need to find and print all the lines which have the same `text` value.
>   For instance, suppose we have 2 lines like the following
>
> - 000000 1234567890123456
> - 111111 1234567890123456
>
> They should be both printed.

Here's my code:

```
r, _ := os.Open("store.txt")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        text := line[7:]
        if !contains(duplicates, text) {
            duplicates = append(duplicates, text)
        } else {
                t, _:= os.Open("store.txt")
                dupScan := bufio.NewScanner(t)
                    //currLine := dupScan.Text()
                for dupScan.Scan() {
                    currLine   := dupScan.Text()
                    currCipher := currLine[7:23]
                    if( currCipher == text ){
                    fmt.Println(currLine)
                    }
                }
                t.Close()
            }
    }
fmt.Println("Done Check")
//Close File
r.Close()

func contains(s []string, e string) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

It works just fine but, since I have million lines, it's really slow. I'm only capable of doing it with a single thread and not using goroutines.

Have you any suggestion on how I should change this code to speed up the check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You have a bug

I don't think your program works as intended. If a line exists \$N > 1\$ times, it will be printed \$N (N - 1)\$ times. Because:

- The first time it's seen, it will be added to `duplicates` and not printed. So far so good.
- The 2nd, 3rd, ... Nth time it's seen, all \$N\$ occurrences will be printed.

When \$N = 2\$, the program will appear to work fine.
But when \$N > 2\$ there will be excess output of duplicates, which is probably not the way you intended.

#### Performance

There are several inefficient operations.

The worst is re-reading the file for every duplicate. If the million lines contain pairs of 500000 values, the file will be read 500001 times.

Another inefficient operation is storing the unique values in a slice, instead of a map. The `contains` implementation based on a slice has  \$O(n)\$ time complexity, which would be \$O(1)\$ using a map.

To improve performance you could use a map of counts. Read the entire file once to build this map. Unique values will have a count of 1, duplicates will have > 1. Read the file again, checking the count in the map, if it's > 1 then print the line.

#### Resource management and error handling

In Go, it's recommended to use `defer` to close resources soon after you opened them, so you don't forget later. So instead of this:

> ```
> fh, err := os.Open(path)
>
> // large block of code
>
> fh.Close()
> ```

It's recommended to write like this:

```
fh, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    panic("could not open file: " + path)
}
defer fh.Close()

// rest of the code
```

Closely related is error handling. You ignored the `error` value returned by `os.Open`, which is not wise. The rest of the program will make little sense if opening the file fails. Always remember and consider to handle errors.

#### Coding style

It's good to run `go fmt` on your program before asking for a review.
It automatically reformats it following the standard of Go.

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above tips together:

```
func main() {
    path := "/tmp/store.txt"
    counts := readCounts(path)
    check(path, counts)
}

func check(path string, counts map[string]int) {
    fh, _ := os.Open(path)
    defer fh.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fh)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        text := line[7:]
        if counts[text] > 1 {
            fmt.Println(line)
        }
    }
}

func readCounts(path string) map[string]int {
    fh, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic("could not open file: " + path)
    }
    defer fh.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fh)
    counts := make(map[string]int)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        text := line[7:]
        counts[text] += 1
    }

    return counts
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough memory to load the whole file at once, this can be done in a single pass.

```
type Status struct {
    Value uint32
    Count uint32 // You said you have millions of records, not billions
}
seen := make(map[uint64]Status)
```

In this map, you store every value you found.

When reading the file, convert each line to its integer values, to save memory. If you have enough memory, it would even be possible to use a `map[string]string`.

Then, for each line, do this:

```
var first, second := parseLine(line)
status := seen[second]
if status.Count == 0 {
    status.Value = first // Remember, but don't print yet
}
status.Count++
seen[second] = status

if status.Count == 2 {
    fmt.Printf("%06x %016x\n", status.Value, second) // The remembered value
}
if status.Count >= 2 {
    fmt.Printf("%06x %016%\n", first, second) // The current value
}
```

To summarize, this code prints all duplicates, and when it finds the second value for a key, it also prints the first value that had been seen.